# Raspberry Pi configuration is not opening when connected via Windows remote desktop connection

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

Raspberry Pi configuration is not opening while connected using windows remote desktop connection or VNC. I'm trying to open it from the main menu. It's opening if I connect RPI to a monitor.

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspbian Stretch with Desktop ?

Comment: Yes. Also I tried to update GUI of the RPi config.

Comment: I'd be tempted to re-flash the latest Raspbian Stretch image to your sd card.

Comment: Open a terminal and type sudo raspi-config

Comment: Could this possibly be a security feature?  I know that there is a GPIO setting which forbids manipulating the GPIOs remotely.  I'm wondering if this is an extension of that.

Comment: If I opens it in terminal it shows. Seems a security feature.

Comment: for me configuration was not opening when using tightvnc-server, configuration open after using realVNC-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using tightvncserver this might help you.

I had VNC enabled in the RPI Configuration (uses realvnc) and installed tightvncserver after that on the RPI. Before that installation it told me that it will remove realvnc. So I guess RPI Configuration got confused with VNC enabled while realvnc had been removed.

Simply removing tightvncserver from the RPI, setting VNC to disable, and installing tightvncserver again did the trick for me.
I probably just could have disabled the realvnc in the RPI configuration via the terminal

`sudo raspi-config` > Interfacing Options > P3 VNC > No (to disable realvnc server)

Or maybe you overruled another setting in the RPI Configuration.

Hope that helps